# Passing value of HTML to jQuery file

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

I have a script like this, and it runs well!

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

the jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //You can alternatively pass an object:

    $('#player').youTubeEmbed({
        video       : 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyeJXKfAcpc',
        width       : 640,      // Height is calculated automatically
        progressBar : true      // Hide the progress bar
    });
});
```

but now I want to make the youtube id in an input value like this:

```
<div id="player">
    <input type="hidden" name="youtube-id" value="uyeJXKfAcpc" />
</div>
```

and pass it to the jquery to be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //You can alternatively pass an object:
    $('#player').youTubeEmbed({
        var yid = $(this).children("input[name='youtube-id']"),
        video       : 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . yid,
        width       : 640,      // Height is calculated automatically
        progressBar : true      // Hide the progress bar
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: i just need to store the value of the hidden input and pass it to varible in the javascript file above, and echo this value after 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' as a varible

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a variable inside an object, move it to above the `youTubeEmbed` plugin, also use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to access the input's value.

```
var yid = $("input[name='youtube-id']").val();
$('#player').youTubeEmbed({
    video           : 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + yid,
    width           : 640,      // Height is calculated automatically
    progressBar : true      // Hide the progress bar
});
```

Comment: @user1576910 are you triggering the javascript (e.g. a button click of some sort)?

Comment: Why are you concatenating the strings with `.`?

Comment: no Sam i'm not, the script is above and is simple as you see without any others codes

Comment: @user1576910 This should work, just replace `.` with `+` => `'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + yid,`

Comment: Thanks @Raminson I should look closer a op code before I copy/paste it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use an input at all. do -

```
<div id="player" data-youtube="uyeJXKfAcpc"></div>
```

Your jQuery -

```
$('#player').youTubeEmbed({
    video: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + $(this).attr('data-youtube'),
    width: 640,
    progressBar: true
});
```

Comment: not working, please download the full script & try it for me: http://www.4shared.com/rar/XoaJijx5/var_pass.html

Comment: please post it online so we don't have to download it

Comment: the solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814183/i-want-to-store-a-value-in-jquery-var-and-pass-it