# i want to store a value in jquery var and pass it

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

i have a script you can download it from here: http://www.4shared.com/rar/XoaJijx5/var_pass.html

the problem is in the index.html & scripts.js, look at and give me the change

i write a comments in the two files to let know what i need

i need to pass the hidden input value to scripts.js and store it in var and echo it in the id url of youtube

the problem in index.html:

```
<div id="player"><input type="hidden" name="youtube-id" value="uyeJXKfAcpc" /></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing value of HTML to jQuery file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813965/passing-value-of-html-to-jquery-file)

Comment: I doubt most users will want to download your script.  Please include the code in the question.  Also as @Musa has already commented this answer is most definitely answered with proper searching.

Comment: Irrelevant... SO provides the means to view formatted code in the question which is what most people expect.  The fact that the script is small is even more of a reason to put it in the question.  When it gets large and includes html/css/javascript users often like to see a jsfiddle.net example.  If you are trying to get HELP make it as easy as possible for the people that are here to help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your code needs to be in $(document).ready function.. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //You can alternatively pass an object:
    $('#player').youTubeEmbed({
        video: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyeJXKfAcpc',
        width: 640,
        // Height is calculated automatically
        progressBar: true // Hide the progress bar
    });

    var yid = $("input[name='youtube-id']").val();
    $('#player').youTubeEmbed({
        video: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + yid,
        width: 640,
        // Height is calculated automatically
        progressBar: true // Hide the progress bar
    });
}); // THE END OF YOUR $(document).ready function
```